# ArrayIndexOutofBoundException in HashMap for setintersection

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
class swap {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Saumil/Saumil/FP.data"));
    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Saumil/Saumil/FP1.data"));
    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] columns = s1.nextLine().split("");
        System.out.println("hi");
        map1.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
    }
    while (s2.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] columns = s2.nextLine().split("");
        System.out.println("123");
        map1.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
    }

    System.out.println(map1);
    try {
    //Map result = new HashMap();

        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(map1.keySet());
        System.out.println("1234");
        s.retainAll(map2.keySet());
        System.out.println(s);


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Saumil/Saumil/output.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);   
        oos.writeObject(s); // write list to ObjectOutputStream
        oos.close(); 
        System.out.println("hi");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Collection intersection=CollectionUtils.intersection(map1.keySet(),map2.keySet());
    s1.close();
    s2.close();
```

I am trying to intersect two hash map.Each hash map get its data from the file which has basically two columns.

its gives me arrayindexoutof bound exception at line no:-14
i.e map1.put(columns[0], columns[1]);

i dont understand why it gives me such exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at swap.main(swap.java:14)

i.e:- map1.put(columns[0], columns[1]);

Comment: please edit that question. the code isn't completely formated, there's no stacktrace, not even a bit of a description about the precise problem...

Comment: I am new to this can u tell me how to edit the question

Comment: there are several options (share, edit, close, flag) below the questiontags. simply click on edit and you can alter the question

Comment: Thanks paul ..you can see th whole code now

Comment: seems like the lines read by the scanner are empty, or maybe theres an empty line somewhere in the file (probably at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check your data files and verify they have the data in correct format.
My guess would be they have some incorrect data. 
You are creating a array of string objects by doing,

```
String[] columns = s1.nextLine().split("");
```

And you are expecting this arrays to have 2 string objects in them. However this may not always be the case, if the file has a bad line.

for example, one line on the file could be like this (line #3)

```
1 col1value1   col1value2
2 col2value1   col2value2
3 col3value1
4 col4value1   col4value2
```

When you convert each line into a array object, it'll generate an array per line on the file. However when it come to line #3 it'll generate an array with one object on it.

When you try to access

```
columns[1]
```

It'll throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this case.

As a debugging step, perhaps print out and check the data before you access the value on these arrays.

or do a try and catch block and under the catch block print out the enter line where it falls over.

```
String tmpStr1 = "";

try {
     tmpStr1 = s1.nextLine();
     columns = tmpStr1.split("");
     //access array items
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aEx) {

    System.out.println(aEx.getMessage());
    //print the whole like that was read from the file
    //this will help you to understand what went wrong
    System.out.println(tmpStr1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro.... i found my mistake...this was just due to file in which every next row was empty...